# Cordova Windows Phone 8 error: ReversePInvokeThunk.OnNavigated

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, navigation

Has anyone come across this error or does someone know a fix for it?

The only line in the stack trace on windows dashboard is :

```
microsoft_phone_interop_ni Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop+ReversePInvokeThunk.OnNavigated 0x68
```

I get quite many of these errors daily, but the one line stack trace does not help me narrow down the situation this occurs in. Thanks.